# How to test the accelerometer for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I'm wondering what is the best way to test the accelerometer?  There doesn't seem to be any simulation for movement on the emulator, and mocking seems like it would be difficult.

Should I just do a best guess and wait until the real devices come out or is there another approach to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://blogs.silverarcade.com/silverlight-games-101/27/silverlight-simulating-accelerometer-data-in-the-windows-phone-7-emulator/

Using this method you can simulate the accelerometer using a Wii Remote, if you have one. Other than that, a quick Google indicates that its not possible without actual hardware. Hope that helps!

Comment: Interesting.  At least I have an excuse to finally get a Wii now.  I'll mark this as the answer later if there are no other suggestions.

Comment: I actually ended up going with a different solution.  Here is a way to fake accelerometer data.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637521(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article on using the accelerator simulation in the emulator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202936(v=vs.105).aspx